# SQL Server ArcSDE ST_Raster Installation and Configuration Error ".dll"

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, .net, arcgis-10.4, sql-server-spatial

I have successfully installed ST_Raster Library in SQL Server machine following this tutorial

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/install-st-raster-oracle.htm

I have used ArcGIS 10.4 Configuration wizard for import and export of configurations
After installation i have also run this query.

> SELECT sde.st_raster_util_getVersion();

After installation i have also run this query.

> SELECT sde.st_raster_util_getVersion();

This query successfully returned the "1000" that means i have successfully installed the ST_raster, i am also able to create a table in SQL Server and from design of the table i can see the type is set ot ST_Raster.

> CREATE TABLE sde.urban_area_sde (raster sde.ST_Raster, name
>   varchar(255));

When initializing the document as tutorial say i used below query to initialize the raster column

```
EXEC sde.ST_Raster_Util_Initialize 'AgriAhDB','sde','urban_area_sde','raster',4326,NULL,'DEFAULTS'
```

It was returned as error.

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure st_raster_util_initialize, Line
>   0 [Batch Start Line 6] A .NET Framework error occurred during
>   execution of user-defined routine or aggregate
>   "st_raster_util_initialize":  System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to
>   load DLL 'pe.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) System.DllNotFoundException:     at
>   ESRI_ArcSDE.STRasterUtil.SdeRasterAPI.pe_factory_coordsys(Int32
>   projectionID)    at
>   ESRI_ArcSDE.STRasterUtil.StoredProcedures.getCoordSysFromPID(SqlInt32
>   projectionID, String& srtext)    at
>   ESRI_ArcSDE.STRasterUtil.StoredProcedures.getCoordSys(SqlInt32
>   projectionID, SqlString projectionFile, String& srtext)    at
>   ESRI_ArcSDE.STRasterUtil.StoredProcedures.createRasterColumn(SqlString
>   database, SqlString owner, SqlString tableName, SqlString columnName,
>   SqlInt32 projectionID, SqlString projectionFile, SqlString keyword,
>   SqlInt32& rastercolumnID, SqlInt32& regID)    at
>   ESRI_ArcSDE.STRasterUtil.StoredProcedures.st_raster_util_initialize(SqlString
>   database, SqlString owner, SqlString tableName, SqlString columnName,
>   SqlInt32 projectionID, SqlString projectionFile, SqlString keyword) .

I have restarted the SQL Server service, but it was unsuccessful in resolving the error. How can I resolve this error,? Is there any specified library that I need to place to use the ST_Raster procedure?

Comment: You linked the Oracle tutorial. Did you mean to link the [proper](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/install-st-raster-sqlserver.htm) one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem related to ArcSDE dll files, that you can get from Bin directory of ArcSDE installations.

Two ways to solve this problem:

1. copy the pe.dll file from C:\program Files\ArcGIS\Server\bin and paste it into c:\Windows\System directory or C:\Windows\System32 directory.
2. You can copy the bin directory path "C:\program Files\ArcGIS\Server\bin" and paste it into You Windows environmental variables **"PATH"** variable.

Comment: The comment box explictly requests that you avoid  commenting with "thanks". The [Help Center](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) recommends you upvote, accept, and "pay it forward".

Comment: Copying DLLs is a future platform stability issue. I'd recommend extensive documentation if you use this route.